# Wikidata item add form template

Tags: programming, wikidata

Is it possible in wikidata to make a template form from which wikidata item is created? If this is not yet supported, what would be simplest way to make (program) such implementation integrated into personal wikidata instance.

I'm looking for something similar as [Semantic forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms) in semantic media wiki, but for wikidata.